# Make pictures under a href 100% height

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I opened similar topics 2,3 times and didn't solved this problem. I'm noob in coding so don't judge. I have wordpress gallery which by default was generating 900x600 images. For small screens it was OK but for 24,27 inches it is really small and it was on top so I decided to change gallery picture sizes to 100% height of a screen with paddings on container for bottom and top. So now I have div with paddings and pictures inside  100% height but they are cropped because of my screen is not lagre for them. I want to figure out how to make my pictures 100% height of my main block which is resizing perfect to all screens. And Also what I mentioned when I open inspector and dragg img from a href up on 1 level they are resizing on the block container which I want. So.. I will give you guys what I have  maybe somebody will give me advice or solution. All answers will be like a gold for me)))

**THis is HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="main gallery">
<div id="frame" style="overflow: hidden;">
<ul class="image-gallery" style="transform: translateZ(0px); width: 6104px;">
 <li class="fade active" data-url-id="764"><a href="" class="thumb full_image" ind="0">
 <img src="http://www.exmple.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/DSC06676print-21x15.-900x1323.jpg" class="attachment-gallery-scroll" ind="0"></a></li>
```

**This is CSS**

```
.container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.gallery {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 120px;
    padding-bottom: 120px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#frame {
    height: 100%;
}


ul.image-gallery {
    height: 100% !important;
}

li.fade {

    height: 100% !Important;
    margin: 0px !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}

a.thumb.full_image {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}

img.attachment-gallery-scroll {
    opacity: 1 !Important;
    height: 100% !Important;
    width: auto !important;

}
```

So when I said before about dragging in code inspector it was like when I change **this**

```
<li class="fade active" data-url-id="764">
<a href="" class="thumb full_image" ind="0">
     <img src="http://www.exmple.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/DSC06676print-21x15.-900x1323.jpg" class="attachment-gallery-scroll" ind="0"></a></li>
```

on **this** image is looking perfect, it is placed in my div which is 100% of my window with paddings on top and botoom.

```
 <li class="fade active" data-url-id="764">
```

If somebody will inspect my [website](http://www.arnoldpiscel.com/storybook/) I'll insert link also. THANKS!!! Will be happy for any help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the "display: table-cell" attribute on the href fixes the problem with the height.

On an unrelated note, you have a header tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device=width">
```

which should probably be

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```